# Why the difference between PowerShell automatic variable $HOME and environment variable $Env:HOME?

Tags: windows, powershell, git, environment-variables

Our organization maps home folders to a network share via Active Directory for each user. This causes issues with Git because Git expects to find the global user config file at the user's home folder, which for me is a mapped drive due to this setting. `git config --global --list` throws `fatal: unable to read config file 'H://.gitconfig': No such file or directory`.

While troubleshooting, I found that the automatic variable `$HOME` in PowerShell is set to `C:\Users\username` but `$Env:HOME` is set to the mapped drive.

Why is PowerShell's automatic variable different? I'm assuming that Active Directory is setting the `$Env:HOME` variable to the mapped drive; is that correct? If so, shouldn't `$HOME` use the same path?

Comment: What is your `homedrive` and `homepath` environment variables?

Comment: H:\ and \ respectively.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**; `$HOME` is preferred for cross-platform compatability

According to the SO post [**getting home directory**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44575585/1366033):

> The most robust way to refer to the current user's home directory is to use **[automatic variable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables?view=powershell-7.2) `$HOME`**.
>
> If you tried to use the **[environment variable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7.2) `$env:HOME`**, platform differences would surface on Windows vs Unix